ARM Cortex M4 context switching: How does the hardware know where xPSR, PC, LR, R12, R3-R0 are on the stack?
I'm working on a context switching mechanism for my RTOS which runs on Cortex-Ms.
When I initialize a task's stack, I have it like this

Then, I decrement the stack pointer 8 times to fit R11-R4.
I initialize task stacks like this:
uint32_t *stack_ptr = stack + stack_size - 1;
    *(--stack_ptr) = (1U << 24);           // xPSR (set bit 24 (T-bit) for thumb)
    *(--stack_ptr) = (uint32_t)task_func;  // PC (task function address)
    *(--stack_ptr) = 0xFFFFFFFD;           // LR (EXC_RETURN)
    stack_ptr -= 5;                        // R12, R3, R2, R1
    *(--stack_ptr) = (uint32_t)parameters; // R0
    stack_ptr -= 8;                        // R11, R10, R9, R8, R7, R6, R5 and R4.

It seems a typical context switch goes like this:
On a context save, you save R4 - R11 onto the top of the task's stack.
Then to restore the next task, R4 - R11 is expected to be on top of the next task's stack.
My question is:
Do R4-R11 strictly need to be at a certain spot on the task stack (the spots i allocated with -= 8), or do they just have to be at the top?
If we save R4-R11 anywhere as long as it's at the top of the stack:
Wouldn't the spot R4-R11 saves at be where PSP is at the time, which can move during the task execution?
If the stack address R4 - R11 gets saved at depends on the moving PSP, then how does the hardware know where to get xPSR, PC, LR, R12, R3-R0? Those are the registers the hardware is responsible for restoring.
Those registers will always be saved on the same spot on the stack, but how does hardware know where on the stack that is?
This is my context switch code.
__asm volatile 
    (
        // Save the context of the current task
        "     mrs r0, psp                     \n" // get current PSP
        "     isb                             \n"
        "     ldr r1, =curr_task              \n" // load address of the pointer curr_task into r1
        "     ldr r2, [r1]                    \n" // load TCB pointed to by curr_task, into r2
        "     stmdb r0!, {r4-r11}             \n" // store r4 - r11 on process stack
        "     str r0, [r2]                    \n" // Save new stack top

        // Update curr_task to next_task
        "     ldr r0, =next_task              \n" // load address of next_task into r0
        "     ldr r2, [r0]                    \n" // load pointer to next_task's TCB
        "     str r2, [r1]                    \n" // update curr_task to point to next_task

        // Restore the context of the next task
        "     ldmia r2!, {r4-r11}             \n" // restore r4-r11 from next_task's stack
        "     msr psp, r2                     \n" // update PSP with next_task->stack_top
        "     bx lr                           \n" // return to the next task
    );

I've found that after a task is finished executing, and this context switch begins to run, the PSP is different from what it was before the task executed.
So this means the PSP must move around during task execution. If it moves around during task execution then how can the hardware know where xPSR, PC, LR, R12, R3-R0 are?
Because I assume it would use PSP to find where those are. If not, then how?

It does not matter that the PSP changes during execution since while the task is executing nothing is saved. Execution is suspended, PSP is frozen, registers are saved, next task's PSP is restored which is unchanged since its context was saved because it was not running so registers can be reloaded.

not sure what you are asking really.  the hardware expects the calling convention is honored and the return address is mostly 0xFFs and that triggers the restoration of registers from the stack.  the hardware does not search for anything.  unless I am misunderstanding the question (the hardware still does not search, you have to do your part right)...

assuming I understand the question the location and order of each item is specific and documented.

@old_timer So I'm basically asking: when a task's PSP is restored, R11 to R4 is restored by the code, and then the hardware needs to restore the other registers like xPSR, PC, LR, R12, R3-R0. How does it find those?

@Jester Yes so my question is how are the other hardware managed registers like xPSR, PC, LR, R12, R3-R0 restored

@TszKitKoon IIRC it's micro coded and the registers are popped off the stack in a set order.  Inquire with the ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual for details.

that is what I was saying too, it is in the arm docs as to what happens on an event, I dont know if the 0xFF... pattern in the link register is fully documented, I dont think it is I know that experimentally

From reading the manual I just realized that the hardware not only pops off the stack on restore but also PUSHES on SAVE. So everything the hardware needs to pop will be there at the PSP. Thanks @old_timer and fuz

it all ties together the use a vector table instead of entry points.  the calling convention is reinforced by hardware, you do not need extra code for an event handler, if the compiler supports the convention you can put the address of the C function in the table directly because the hardware saves state and then restores it on the way out.   historically you wrap your handlers with asm or tell the compiler it is a handler and they wrap it but the hardware does it for this solution.

as with any processor you need to know how it works so you can implement your task switcher, etc...

it is not an x86/cisc, so not microcoded.
